# TLS where to put certificates

Tags: java, ssl, truststore

I created three certificates -- for the root CA, the intermediate CA and the server. They represent the simple chain of trust:

```
server -> intermediate -> root
```

The question is how correctly put them on the client and the server.
I have two options:

1. Put **root** certificate in the client *trustStore* and other -- **intermediate** and **server** certificates to the server *keyStore*. Thus server will send two certificates and client will validate server certificate with intermediate which will be validated with root certificate stored in client's trustStore.
2. Put **root** and **intermediate** certificates to client *trustStore* when the server will store only its own certificate in *keyStore*.

Enlighten me :)

Comment: Are your certificates from a trusted CA or self-signed?

Comment: @devang self-signed -- I generated all certificates using OpenSSL

Comment: Since self-signed, your steps are correct for server side setup. Additionally, you will have to put the root-ca in truststore on the client side, and also put the root-ca in `/etc/ssl/certs` dir and run `ca_rehash`. Verify that you openssl connect with server is correct using `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port>`. Putting in /etc/ssl/certs is required only if you are planning to make http calls from command line, e.g. curl/wget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I've set up web servers with intermediate certificates I've put the intermediate certs on the server. Its the server's job to prove its identity to the client, and to do this it sends out the certificate hierarchy (intermediate certs) between the webserver certificate and the trusted root, as the client may not have these.
So your option 1 would be the way to go I think.

Comment: According to the standard (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-7.4.2 et pred) this is required, although people do sometimes cheat and _some_ browsers or clients _may_ try to cope.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install *both* the root and the intermediate certs in the client truststore. That's just redundant. Which you install depends who you want the client to trust. Typically that will be the root CA, so you will only install that at the client. If for some reason you only want the client to trust the intermediate CA, you would only install that.